# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'F01' to data type int

Tags: t-sql

It appears that `[t_l_unit]` being a `varchar` is conflicting with the filters in my Where clause.  Can I fix this with a `Cast` of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

Going by the title of your post, your are trying to convert the value "F01" to an INT?

Obviously this is not possible because of the "F" in the string.

What you can do is use the TRY_CAST function which will convert the value to an INT if it can and will return NULL otherwise

```
SELECT val1, va2, etc
FROM myTable
WHERE TRY_CAST([t_l_unit] as INT) = 12
```

Comment: or you could just use a varchar in you WHERE, which might perform a little better.  Eg.,  `SELECT val1, va2, etc
FROM myTable
WHERE [t_l_unit] = '12'`

Answer (score -1):

The query didn't come through, but you should be able to just do:

```
CAST([t_l_unit] AS INT)
```

to use it as a number in your where clause.